# django-admin.py from Scripts or Lib

Tags: python, django, windows, environment-variables

There is python and django framework installed. I want to add to windows environment path the `django-admin.py` script but dont know which path is proper. What is the difference/purpose of them?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "Why are the both of them" ?

Comment: Use http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/